# Facebook Like Box doesn't work

Tags: javascript, facebook

I've been having a problem with a facebook like-box for a client, and me and a friend simply can't figure out what we're doing wrong, and it's been close to three days of staring at it. Here's the code we get from developers.facebook.com:

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));</script>
    <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/mywebsite/11111111111"      
data-width="280" data-colorscheme="dark" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div>
```

Nothing shows up. We did get this piece of code to work, but it doesn't quite work the way we want to:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/mywebsite/1111111111" width="280" colorscheme="dark" show_faces="true" border_color="" stream="true" header="false"></fb:like-box>
```

You have to log in to facebook to see the feed, but the client want it to always show up.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add http: in line 5 of the head script like this...

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
```

its a html5 thing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try the latest code; Facebook appear to have modified the [Like box generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/#).

Comment: You're right, the code is different, but the result is the same, mainly in that nothing shows up still. 

However, I did stumble upon a solution using the old code, since I could get that to at least show up in the page. It was just a permissions restriction  on the facebook page, and once I removed it, that old piece of code worked like a charm. I'm still curious as to why the new code fails to work, though.